# Long text in TextView make the layouts to get 'Out of Scope'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, textview

I am facing an issue where my layouts *get out of scope* as soon as the text in `TextViews` get bigger.

Following is the code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Home" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/call_log_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#00ccff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/call_log"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/call_log_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#993399" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recent_activities_titles"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/recent_activities"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/recent_activities_table"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recent_activities_titles" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/r_new_lead_row"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView20"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/r_new_lead"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/new_lead_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Michell"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/r_new_account_row"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView21"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/r_new_account"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/r_new_account_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Donna"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView22"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/r_new_event"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView23"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="Meeting with some people I have never seen befpre"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you see, there are lot of nested layouts, that is because you see only one portion of a mass scale program. So nested layouts is not an issue.

In `textView23`, if I put a small text like "Meeting", this is how the UI output looks.

[image]

This is the correct and the output I need.

But, If I put a big text into it, this is how the output looks

[image]

As you can see, it is out of bounds, even overtaking the other layout's space. Not only for the `textview23`, the same issue will happen with other `textviews` as well.

Now my question is, no matter how long the text is, how can I keep the layouts as the first image?

`Max Width` attribute of a TextView might not be the best answers, because this is for multiple screens and will give lot of issues then.

Maybe, if the text is too long, marquee it? Or only to display what the text view layout can show, and display the rest when the user swipe the textview to left? Any other way? I don't know how to make any of these work.

Answer (score 1):

As you want it to work for multiple resolutions and sizes,

the better way would be to limit the text length and show marquee at the end.

something like this

```
android:maxLength="10" 
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Inside your `ScrollView` remove `RelativeLayout` replace with `LinearLayout`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

//Your Remaining Content

</LinearLayout>
```

then your  `RelativeLayout` `relativeLayout4`

as

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/call_log_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#993399" >
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. The issue is, in original code, I can't make it LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have put your width attribute - wrap_content

First define a fixed width, say 100dp
put property maxLine = 1, and ellipsize = end

For Example, in your code :-

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Meeting with some people I have never seen befpre"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Use This :-

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Meeting with some people I have never seen befpre"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"    
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

ellipsize will put "..." at some point in between your screen, if your text is bigger than the specified width of your textview, and the text after "..." will get chopped off.

Comment: fixed width won't do it. It need to be scaled with the screen

Comment: You question was this "no matter how long the text is, how can I keep the layouts as the first image?"
So for this, you need to ellpisize your text if you want the first image in case of a long text.,.
i have implemented this at 50 different places in my project.,, the only solution was to ellipsize it so that my layouts should
not get disrupted